# Background Image not showing up on iphone/tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media

I have a background image that's not showing up on the iphone/tablet! The funny thing is that if you use a laptop but set the window size to that of an iphone/tablet, it still shows up (try resizing the site).

```
#intro {
background: url('imageurlhere') no-repeat right fixed;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
-webkit-background-size: 50% 125%;
-moz-background-size: auto 125%;
-o-background-size: auto 125%;
background-size: auto 125%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='imageurlhere', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='imageurlhere', sizingMethod='scale')";
padding-top: 10%;
}
```

if i take off the "fixed" parameter, it will show but parallax will be gone.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What size is the background image? Apple have rules on image sizes and this has resulted in peoples background images not be visible.

Comment: Width: 603, Height: 1371! Hmmm so these image size rules apply even with background resizing in the CSS? Also, I tried it using the WebOS browser and the same issue occurred :/ 
I tested using the chrome and safari browser on the ipad/iphone

Comment: If it's working on desktops etc then you know the CSS and file path are correct. It seems a little large, it must be iOS blocking it. A way round it would be to slice it into 2 and then stack them making them appear as one.

Comment: I just used a media query and used a smaller image on mobile devices, didn't work. And if that were the case, then taking off "fixed" shouldn't make a difference :/

Comment: fixed has issues with ios. This methos fixes it (technique 2) http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the position-y: fixed of the convenience property.

Safari on iOS didn't recognize `fixed` so it ignored the whole rule (see attached screenshot).

[image]

Remove:

```
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/CVJVeWw.jpg) no-repeat right fixed;
```

and add instead:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto 125%;
background-position-x: right;
background-position-y: fixed;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CVJVeWw.jpg);
```

**Update** see `background-position-y` and `background-attachment: fixed`

I played with this a bit more to see if I could get it working a bit better for you.  For some reason, when both `background-attachment: fixed;` and `background-position-x: right;` are specified on iOS 6x, the background goes missing.  However, by resetting `background-attachment: fixed;` to `initial` the image displays although you do lose the parallax.

So: try this for desktop:

```
#intro {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/rKJbwgL.jpg);
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    -webkit-background-size: 110% 110%;
    -moz-background-size: auto 125%;
    -o-background-size: auto 125%;
    background-size: auto 110%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://i.imgur.com/rKJbwgL.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://i.imgur.com/rKJbwgL.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    padding-top: 10%;
    margin-right: -10%;
}
```

Then in a media query for phone/tablet, reset background-attachment:

```
background-attachment: initial;
```

Let me know if that works a bit better for you.

Comment: I'm in chrome in-browser and background-position-y isn't being recognized

Comment: iOS still works though -right?  I'm in chrome on desktop and your site looks correct.  There is something strange happening with background-position though.  Chrome shows an error but if you delete the style in the inspector, it messes up your layout.